# R package build server

Tags: r

My company is setting up an internal CRAN-like repository. We can push packages up to the server if they are built locally, but we don't have a good way to produce windows binaries for multiple versions of R. Instead we end up with one binary (built against whatever version of R the person releasing the package happened to be using) and one source distribution.

How does CRAN do it? Is there a way to set up a build server that will take a source distribution and build windows binaries against a certain number of R versions? This has become an issue because R 3.1.* and R 3.2.* binaries are not cross-compatible.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? How do you push packages to the server?

Comment: I have a related question: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/45467/1834